# Trying to print a display row-by-row, by adding rows together in a single, multi-line string

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x, rows

I am trying to print out a series of die that will display as below:

```
   ___     ___     ___     ___     ___
  |*  |   |*  |   |* *|   |*  |   |   |
  |   |   | * |   |* *|   | * |   | * |
  |  *|   |  *|   |* *|   |  *|   |   |
   ^^^     ^^^     ^^^     ^^^     ^^^
```

These die should represent the numbers that are produced when I 'roll the dice'. I have created a Die class and a Hand class, and they are produced below.

```
import random

class Die():

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = random.randint(1,6)

    def roll(self):
        self.value = random.randint(1,6)

    '''def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)'''
```

---

```
import Die


class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.L=[]
        for i in range(5):
            self.L.append(Die.Die()) #makes the number of dice



    def __str__(self):
        """converts hand to a string for printing"""
        return "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}".format(self.L[0], self.L[1], self.L[2], self.L[3], self.L[4])

    def roll(self, keep):
        for i in range(5):
            if i+1 not in keep:
                self.L[i].roll()
```

The code given above will produce a list of numbers when the main file enters

```
h = hand.Hand()
h.roll() #this rolls the hand again
print(h)
```

Any ideas how I can get my results to print in the provided display style? It has been suggested that the best way to do it is to print three rows to construct all 5 dice. 
The most recent advice was "You have to
build the entire display of dice row-by-row, then add the rows together
in a single, multi-line string." I'm just not sure how to execute that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
DIE_PARTS = [
    ['___'] * 6,
    ['   ', '*  ', '*  ', '* *', '* *', '* *'],
    [' * ', '   ', ' * ', '   ', ' * ', '* *'],
    ['   ', '  *', '  *', '* *', '* *', '* *'],
    ['^^^'] * 6,
]

DIE_SPACING = ' ' * 3


def print_hand(dies):
    # Build line parts
    lines = [[],[],[],[],[]]
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        for d in dies:
            if i in [1,2,3]: edge = '|'
            else:            edge = ' '
            part = ''
            part += edge                # Leading edge of die
            part += DIE_PARTS[i][d-1]   # "pips"
            part += edge                # Trailing edge of die
            line.append(part)

    # Join lines
    lines = [DIE_SPACING.join(l) for l in lines]

    # Print lines
    for l in lines: print(l)


print_hand([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Output:

```
 ___     ___     ___     ___     ___     ___ 
|   |   |*  |   |*  |   |* *|   |* *|   |* *|
| * |   |   |   | * |   |   |   | * |   |* *|
|   |   |  *|   |  *|   |* *|   |* *|   |* *|
 ^^^     ^^^     ^^^     ^^^     ^^^     ^^^
```

If it's not clear, you're building each line of the 5 line output, line by line, then die for die.

So it goes something like

```
line 1 - die 1, line 1 - die 2, line 1 - die 3, ... 
line 2 - die 1, line 2 - die 2, line 2 - die 3, ...
...
line 5 - die 1, line 5 - die 2, line 5 - die 3, ...
```

Then it joins the parts of the lines list using `DIE_SPACING` as the delimiter.

I'll leave integrating this into the rest of your code up to you.

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you. I keep receiving an error that says:

`line 102, in print_hand
    part += DIE_PARTS[i][d-1]   # "pips"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`

Any idea how I can get this to work with the string? Very new to python still..

Comment: @HRogers Did you change something?  You shouldn't have gotten that error with the code I listed.  If so, can you edit your question to show your updated code?

Comment: I've been messing around with it to try to fit the hand that is rolled into 

`print_hand([1,2,3,4,5,6])`

The hand is currently returned as a string from the hand class, rather than as a list, so I need to figure out how to make these two pieces compatible.

Comment: @HRogers oh I understand.  Well if you can make a list of the die values from the hand, you can pass that to `print_hand()` -- that's all the function cares about, a list of integers whose values are in [1,6].

Comment: the issue is pretty deeply embedded because the Die class returns the individual integers each as a string...and then the hand class produces a string of strings. Is there any way to change your suggested solution to work with strings?

Comment: @HRogers Sure, assuming that you have a string like `s = "1,2,3,4,5"` (which it appears like you might, given your `Die` and `Hand` class), you *could* "reverse" that string to a list of integers with something like `ints = [int(x) for x in s.split()]` -- then call `print_hand(ints)`.